Why does elementTree break CGI file when printing to HTML?
I'm trying to create a simple CGI program that will output XML to an HTML webpage.  In the course of debugging, I noticed that tree = ET.parse(path) prevents HTML from displaying on the webpage.
Here's my code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import cgi
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')

# ------get field data-------
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fn = form.getvalue('fname','Steve')
ln = form.getvalue('lname','')
email = form.getvalue('email','')
comments = form.getvalue('comments','')

#------get xml data---------
path = '/formdata.txt'
print('html works') #<--- Prints in terminal AND browser
tree = ET.parse(path)
print('html works') #<--- Prints in terminal but NOT browser
root = tree.getroot()

#------add submission child and subchilds-----
subm = ET.SubElement(root,'submission')

fnElem = ET.SubElement(subm, "firstname")
fnElem.text = fn
lnElem = ET.SubElement(subm, "lastname")
lnElem.text = ln
emailElem = ET.SubElement(subm, "email")
emailElem.text = email
commentsElem = ET.SubElement(subm, "comments")
commentsElem.text = comments

#-------write new tree to file---------
tree.write(path)


I tried printing "html works" after ET.parse(path), but I can only get the print statement to display in the terminal while debugging the code.
I want the print statement to display when the file is run from a browser.  If I move the print statement to before the ET.parse(path) line, it works.

You can add a reference to a .xsd file, where you have to define the the html layout.
